# Ubuntu Apache2 - restrict access by IP address

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, authentication

In Ubuntu 11.04, I'm trying to [Allow from IP without password prompt, and also allow from any address with password prompt](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-authentication-in-htaccess.html#allow-conditional). But it isn't working.
Everyone from the Internet can access the page without the password.
If I set simple password authentication (without conditions), it works.

Help!

Comment: Some more info: Since .htaccess files are deprecated I edited the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file

Comment: Post the relevant bits of your Apache config, please.

Comment: `<Directory /var/www>`

`Order deny,allow`

`Deny from all`

`AuthName "htaccess password prompt"`

`AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd`

`AuthType Basic`

`Require user xxxxx`

`Allow from 1xx.xx.xx.120`

`Satisfy Any`

`</Directory>`

Comment: Sorry for the missing line breaks. I tried four-space indentation but it didn't work.

Comment: what issues are you facing exactly? You state, ""If I set simple password authentication (without conditions), it works.". If it works -what are you trying to resolve? To do what you are looking for, you have to use htaccess and htpasswd files.

Comment: I need password authentication *with* conditions. Users whose IP address is *not* a specific one need to enter a password.
Follow the link in my original post. The technique described there doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to block requests completely from other IP's you can do:

```
<Directory /var/www/sub/payroll/>
Order deny,allow
deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.1
</Directory>
```

It blocks requests from all IP's except the one you specified.

If you want to password promt using .htaccess try this link:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-apache-password-protect-directory-with-htaccess-file/

Comment: No I don't want to block requests from other IPs completely. They should have access after entering a password.
I'd rather not use .htaccess files.

Comment: I think you can put it in the apache2 configuration aswell, if you'd rather want that.

Comment: I tried it using .htaccess — still no luck.

Comment: Are you getting any errors, or is it just not working?

Comment: It is not working — Internet users are supposed to get a password prompt. Instead they can view the page without entering the username/password.
Form the allowed IP address, access is OK.

Comment: The link only restricts access to an actual folder. If you need to password protect an URL, that has nothing to do with a folder, you're probably going to have to make it in the software layer ie. using PHP or ASP

Comment: I want to restrict access to all files in the folder. BTW, Apache can also protect a single file with this syntax
     <Files "mypage.html">
     Require valid-user
     </Files>

If I don't find a solution to this I'm going to use PHP. But it is a pain to do this for each HTML file and for binary files.

Comment: You could just include a simple php file that makes the check on all pages, or use a framework or page loader CMS, with a specific rule to request log in, if not from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx IP.